# TFS 2015 warehouse job error: TF221123: Job Version Control Warehouse Sync

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2012, tfs-2015

We have recently migrated from TFS 2010 to TFS 2015 (Update 2) and everything seems to work fine apart from 
the following error we get every 12 minutes.

```
TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:

Application Domain: TfsJobAgent.exe
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 

Detailed Message: TF221123: Job Version Control Warehouse Sync for team project collection JLT TFS 2010 was unable to run after 20 attempts.
```

After checking "Process status" through the "Warehouse Control Web Service" I get the following message. 
I would like to understand the core reason of why this is happening and how we can resolve this isue?

```
<Job JobProcessingStatus="DataChange" Name="Version Control Warehouse Sync">
    <LastRun Result="Stopped" EndTimeUtc="2016-06-30T14:10:50.19Z" ExecutionStartTimeUtc="2016-06-30T14:00:49.877Z" QueueTimeUtc="2016-06-30T14:00:49.203Z">
        <ResultMessage>
            [Version Control Warehouse Sync]: ---> MakeDataChanges() result=DataChangesPending. 
            ---> MakeDataChanges() result=DataChangesPending. 
            ---> MakeDataChanges() result=DataChangesPending. 
            ---> MakeDataChanges() result=DataChangesPending. ---> 
            ...
            ...
            ---> TF221123: Job Version Control Warehouse Sync for team project collection JLT TFS 2010 was unable to run after 20 attempts.    
        </ResultMessage>
    </LastRun>
    <CurrentRun ExecutionStartTimeUtc="2016-06-30T14:12:50.75Z" QueueTimeUtc="2016-06-30T14:12:50.19Z" JobState="Running"/>
</Job>
```

Comment: Seems related to your sql server, did you get any error or related info with your sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking this further we found that this is a known issues (confirmed by Microsoft) and has been fixed in TFS 2015 (Update 3).

Although, it requires to apply the latest Update of TFS 2015, however, it can be achieved by applying the following workaround at database level.

Please run the following script on the TFS Collection Database

```
DECLARE @partitionId INT = 1
DECLARE @registryUpdates typ_KeyValuePairStringTableNullable
INSERT  @registryUpdates ([Key], Value)
SELECT  ‘#\Configuration\VersionControl\CodeChurn\InUpgrade\’, NULL
EXEC prc_UpdateRegistry @partitionId, @registryUpdates
DROP TABLE tbl_UpgradeCodeChurn
```

Detailed information can be [found in the following article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wlennon/2016/06/08/235/).

After running this script and leaving it for few hours resolved this reported issue.